# Thingsboard database installation failed

Tags: thingsboard

When trying to install using cmd:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\thingsboard>install.bat --loadDemo
```

Thingsboard prompt me this error:

> Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start ThingsBoard installation failed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Build thingsboard project by using `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dlicense.skip`
2. Add `thingsboard` database
3. go to `application\target\windows` and run `install_dev_db.bat`

Answer (score 0):

`run install.bat` as administrator privilege.

And check if is there any application is using 8080 with `netstat -a` in cmd